# What is the relation between temperature and electromagnetic radiation emitted by a body?

Tags: thermodynamics

I have read in thermodynamics that a body with high temperature radiates electromagnetic radiation. Does the frequency of waves increases with temperature? What is the mechanism? How does temperature does that?

Comment: Look up the Planck Law, along with Stefan Boltzmann law and Wien's law. Those laws, along with their derivations, will cover these questions.

Comment: I do not think you have made any effort to look for an answer, eg using a search engine, before posting your question. The information you require is already widely available on the internet, eg Wikipedia. I do not think it is the purpose of this site to regurgitate such information.